# {"message":"Invalid Basic Auth Header","traceID":""} GRAFANA

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-loki, grafana-alerts, grafana-api

I installed grafana on my Linux VM using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -y adduser libfontconfig1
wget https://dl.grafana.com/enterprise/release/grafana-enterprise_9.5.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i grafana-enterprise_9.5.2_amd64.deb
```

The i enabled and started the grafana server:

```
sudo systemctl enable grafana-server
sudo systemctl start grafana-server
```

Grafana Server shows ACTIVE

But when i try to open it in the web browser `http://ip_address:3000/`, i get the following error:
`{"message":"Invalid Basic Auth Header","traceID":""}`

I checked if there is a firewall problem, but there is none.
As i am new to grafana, i would be very thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: I believe this question is off-topic on SO. Something like [su] or [sf] could be better suited for this. On the other hand, I'd recommend you to consider asking questions about grafana enterprise in support.